# Kusto: How summarize calculated data

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have start and end calculated columns which I have read from Table1.
And comparing the how many events are happened in this between time .

```
Input Data:
    let Mytable1=datatable (Vin:string,start_time:datetime ,End_time:datetime )
    [ABC,datetime(2021-03-18 08:49:08.467), datetime(2021-03-18 13:32:28.000),
    ABC,datetime(2021-03-18 13:41:59.323),datetime(2021-03-18 13:41:59.323),
    ABC,datetime(2021-03-18 13:46:59.239),datetime(2021-03-18 14:58:02.000)];

    let Mytable2=datatable(Vin:string,Timestamp:datetime)
    [ABC,datetime(2021-03-18 08:49:08.467),ABC,datetime(2021-03-18 08:59:08.466),ABC,datetime(2021-03-18 09:04:08.460),ABC,datetime(2021-03-18 13:24:27.0000000)];
```

Query:

```
let Test=Table1 
|where Vin =="ABC" | distinct Vin,Start_Time,End_Time;
let min1=toscalar(Test |summarize min1= min(Start_Time));
let max1=toscalar(Test |summarize max1=max(End_Time));
Table2
|where Vin =="ABC" and  Timestamp between (todatetime(min1) ..todatetime(max1))
| join  kind=fullouter   Test
on  $left.Vin == $right.Vin and $left.Timestamp== $right.Start_Time 
|summarize Events= (count())  by Timestamp,Vin,Start_Time,End_Time
|project Timestamp,Start_Time,End_Time,Events
```

Output of above query is :
[image]
But My expected output is :
[image]
Means Events count from between two  start and end time.

Comment: It's hard to understand how the output is supposed to be calculated. Please edit the question, and provide minimal sample input (in datatable format), the expected output for this input, and an explanation on how it's supposed to be calculated, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Hey, I have add input data as well

Comment: Your sample input data doesn't match the schema (column names and types) expected by the query. Please edit the question, to have the sample data, query, current and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have timestamp in your final aggregation. A working example could look like:

```
let measurement_range=datatable (vin:string,start_time:datetime ,end_time:datetime )
["ABC",datetime(2021-03-18 08:49:08.467),datetime(2021-03-18 13:32:28.000),
 "ABC",datetime(2021-03-18 13:41:59.323),datetime(2021-03-18 13:44:59.323),
 "ABC",datetime(2021-03-18 13:46:59.239),datetime(2021-03-18 14:58:02.000),
 ];
let measurement=datatable(vin:string,timestamp:datetime)
    ["ABC",datetime(2021-03-18 08:49:08.467),
     "ABC",datetime(2021-03-18 08:59:08.466),
     "ABC",datetime(2021-03-18 09:04:08.460),
     "ABC",datetime(2021-03-18 13:42:27.0000000)];
measurement_range
| join kind=inner (measurement) 
        on vin     
| where timestamp between (start_time..end_time)
| summarize event=(count()) by vin, start_time, end_time
```

With this you get a count for your measurement window. In this example you get a large intermediate resultset, as the timerange is considered in the where statement.
Please see the [Azure Data Explorer Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/join-timewindow) how to optimize time window joins (the example is not efficient for larger datasets).